# A better way to do this with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, reactjs

Well.. I'm new in ReactJS, I'm AngularJS developer.

I have a problem... I need click on link and render a  with a youtube iframe video.

I did, but...

Below the code:

```
<div class="news-box -hero">
  <a href="#" class="news-cover -play -video">
    <img src="images/news4.jpg" alt="" class="cover">

    <div class="video-box" video-id="uoNPBcEBmFg"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="news-info" style="border-color: #174489">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Date and Hours</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I need that when click on '.-video' shows youtube iframe inside '.video-box'.

Will have many '.-video'.

I did so:

```
/**
 * Video
 */
var VideoBox = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <iframe width="70%" height="100%" src={'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.props.videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1'} frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
    );
  }
});

/**
 * When click on '-video'
 */
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('.-video');

for (var i = 0, t = videos.length; i < t; i++) {
  var video = videos[i];

  video.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var videoBox = video.querySelector('.video-box'),
        id = videoBox.getAttribute('video-id');

    React.render(
      <VideoBox videoId={id} />,
      videoBox
    );

    videoBox.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
```

Yes, it works! There is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have the `news-box` thing as a react component too ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using React that way, with a mix of traditional DOM event handling and a little bit of React code? It would be easier if you restructured the entire block to use React I would imagine, especially from a manipulation and eventing pattern.

Comment: The site will be created in Wordpress, my idea is learn React using this project. The idea is like this: http://recordit.co/xi982Gja4e

There is a better idea for this using React or isn't a good idea use it? Thanks!

Comment: writing everything in React (if you are using react) would be better in my opinion.

Comment: So React is most useful for AJAX calls? For example, the home page of this project I will have a widget for weather and I will request an API, in this case the React is more useful?

Comment: you can add an onclick you your .video class if you just make it a react component, you should move the whole thing over to React, it would be much nicer.